# Can 2 VMs added under common DC, would able to perform Kerberos Windows Authentication to MsSQL Server without username/Password?

Tags: java, sql-server, kerberos

I've added 2 VM's under common DC and logged In both machine using same user. e.g. `administrator`

I want to check if my MsSQL Server running on VM1 and from VM2 if I execute below java code pointing to MsSQL Server of VM1, would able to do 'Windows Authentication' without providing username/Password? (Since, I logged in on both machine using same DC user?)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
 
/**
 * This program demonstrates how to establish database connection to Microsoft
 * SQL Server.
 *
 */
public class JdbcSQLServerConnection {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        Connection conn = null;
 
        try {
 
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://<ip of machine 1 where MsSQL Server>:1433;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=javaKerberos";//;authentication=NotSpecified
            String user = "myrandomUsers";
            String pass = "myrandomPwd";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            }
 
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error as below

```
C:\Users\Administrator.WIN2016\Desktop\MsSQL1>java -cp mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar
; JdbcSQLServerConnection
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot login with Kerberos prin
cipal administrator, check your credentials. Kerberos Login failed: Integrated a
uthentication failed. ClientConnectionId:40a56fce-e909-483d-ab1d-56900d44311d du
e to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException (Pre-authentication information wa
s invalid (24))
```

it is not working at my end.. I'm trying to check whether my expectations connections to establish without valid username/pwd is correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking here. It *seems* you're asking "will this work", however, you're in a far better position to test if it will or not as you're in the environment the script will be run in. If the script isn't running as you expect, then tell us why it isn't.

Comment: Have you read through [Using Kerberos integrated authentication to connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server) yet?

Comment: @Larnu since it is not working at my end.. I'm trying to check whether my expectations connections to establish without valid username/pwd is correct ?

Comment: Yes, you can be logged in with the same user on two different machines. Kerberos doesn't use username and password, so not sure why you are passing those. When you say "logged in" does that mean that the *currently logged in Windows user* is that? Also, are both VMs and the SQL Server machine part of the same domain?

Comment: Yep.. you got it right. Thanks @Charlieface

Comment: Can you post the full text of the login failure as it shows in the SQL Server Log (you can get this in SSMS on the left side), please include Error Number and Error Severity